# UTF8ToUTF16 failing

Tags: c++11, unicode, utf-8, visual-studio-2013, utf-16

I have the following code which is just three sets of functions for converting UTF8 to UTF16 and vice-versa. It converts using 3 different techniques..

However, all of them fail:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::string &data)
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    DWORD slen = data.size();
    WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), data.c_str(), data.size(), &slen, nullptr);
    return os;
}

std::wostream& operator <<(std::wostream& os, const std::wstring &data)
{
    DWORD slen = data.size();
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), data.c_str(), slen, &slen, nullptr);
    return os;
}

std::wstring AUTF8ToUTF16(const std::string &data)
{
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().from_bytes(data);
}

std::string AUTF16ToUTF8(const std::wstring &data)
{
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(data);
}

std::wstring BUTF8ToUTF16(const std::string& utf8)
{
    std::wstring utf16;
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    if (len > 1)
    {
        utf16.resize(len - 1);
        wchar_t* ptr = &utf16[0];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8.c_str(), -1, ptr, len);
    }
    return utf16;
}

std::string BUTF16ToUTF8(const std::wstring& utf16)
{
    std::string utf8;
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    if (len > 1)
    {
        utf8.resize(len - 1);
        char* ptr = &utf8[0];
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16.c_str(), -1, ptr, len, 0, 0);
    }
    return utf8;
}

std::string CUTF16ToUTF8(const std::wstring &data)
{
    std::string result;
    result.resize(std::wcstombs(nullptr, &data[0], data.size()));
    std::wcstombs(&result[0], &data[0], data.size());
    return result;
}

std::wstring CUTF8ToUTF16(const std::string &data)
{
    std::wstring result;
    result.resize(std::mbstowcs(nullptr, &data[0], data.size()));
    std::mbstowcs(&result[0], &data[0], data.size());
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "консоли";

    MessageBoxA(nullptr, str.c_str(), str.c_str(), 0); //Works Fine!

    std::wstring wstr = AUTF8ToUTF16(str);  //Crash!
    MessageBoxW(nullptr, wstr.c_str(), wstr.c_str(), 0); //Fail - Crash + Display nothing..

    wstr = BUTF8ToUTF16(str);
    MessageBoxW(nullptr, wstr.c_str(), wstr.c_str(), 0); //Fail - Random chars..

    wstr = CUTF8ToUTF16(str);
    MessageBoxW(nullptr, wstr.c_str(), wstr.c_str(), 0); //Fail - Question marks..

    std::cin.get();
}
```

The only thing that works above is the `MessageBoxA`. I don't understand why because I'm told that Windows converts everything to UTF16 anyway so why can't I convert it myself?
Why does none of my conversions work?

Is there a reason my code does not work?

Comment: Better: use the smallish header-only `boost::nowide`. No boost required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem why all of your approaches fail is that they require the `std::string` to be UTF-8 encoded but `std::string str = "консоли"` **is not UTF-8 encoded unless you save the .cpp file as UTF-8 and configure your compiler's default codepage to UTF-8.**  In most C++11 compilers, you can use the `u8` prefix to force the string to use UTF-8:

```
std::string str = u8"консоли";
```

However, VS 2013 does not support that feature yet:

[Support For C++11 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

> Unicode string literals
>   2010 No
>   2012 No
>   2013 No

Windows itself does not support UTF-8 in most API functions that take a `char*` as input (an exception is `MultiByteToWideChar()` when using `CP_UTF8`).  When you call an `A` function, it calls the corresponding `W` function internally, converting any `char*` data to/from UTF-16 using Windows' default codepage (`CP_ACP`).  So you get random results when you use non `CP_ACP` data with functions that are expecting it.   As such, `MessageBoxA()` will work correctly only if your .cpp file and compiler are using the same codepage as `CP_ACP` so the unprefixed `char*` data matches what `MessageBoxA()` is expecting.

I don't know why `AUTF8ToUTF16()` is crashing, probably a bug in your compiler's STL implementation when processing bad data.

`BUTF8ToUTF16()` is not handling this case in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "If the input byte/char sequences are invalid, returns U+FFFD for UTF encodings."  Also, your implementation is not optimal. Use `length()` instead of `-1` on inputs to avoid dealing with null terminator issues.

`CUTF8ToUTF16()` is not doing any error handling or validations. However converting non-valid input to question marks or U+FFFD is very common in most libraries.

Comment: The `u8` prefix only ensures that the string will be encoded as utf8 in the executable. It does not mean that the source code text will be interpreted as UTF8. So you're still relying on the compiler to read the source code as the correct encoding

Comment: The compiler interprets the source in whatever encoding it is set to, but will ensure the character string is processed as Unicode when generating the UTF-8 octets, so as long as the source and compiler are using an encoding that produces the correct Unicode sequence then it will work fine.  But yes, it would be best to force the encoding when possible.

Comment: I saved the files with `UTF-8 65001 codepage with BOM` in visual studio's `advanced save options` under the file menu. No cigar. I added error checking, all of it works fine it just doesn't do the conversion.. The conversion seems to work fine in gcc.. In fact, the MessageBoxA in gcc fails but the MessageBoxW works fine.. Complete opposite of Visual Studio :S The `mbstowcs` fails in gcc though.